# How to select records from one table in which other record should not be present in it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. SubjectTbl and SubjectAllotTbl.

This is my SubjectTbl

```
+------------+--------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+----------+
| Subject_Id | Subject_Code | Subject_Name        | Periods_Week | Dep_Id | Semester |
+------------+--------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+----------+
|          1 |         6012 | Basic Electronics   |           10 |      1 |        1 |
|          2 |         5412 | Computer Science    |            7 |      1 |        3 |
|          3 |         1421 | Musical Science     |            4 |      1 |        5 |
|          4 |          547 | Network Programming |            7 |      1 |        5 |
+------------+--------------+---------------------+--------------+--------+----------+
```

and SubjectAllotTbl

```
+------------+------------+
| Subject_Id | Teacher_Id |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |          1 |
|          2 |          3 |
|          3 |          2 |
+------------+------------+
```

All i want to do is selecting Subject_Name from table SubjectTbl in which Same subject_id Should not be present in the SubjectAllotTbl

I'm using MySql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select subject_name
from SubjectTbl
where subject_id not in ( select distinct subject_id from SubjectAllotTbl)
```

You probably don't need distinct, unless subject_id is repeating in SubjectAllotTbl for different teacher_id

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a `left join`: all the rows that don't join will have `null` values on `SubjectAllotTbl` columns, and so you filter the result on that.

```
select  subject_name
from    SubjectTbl t1
left join
        SubjectAllotTbl t2
on      t1.subject_id = t2.subject_id
where   t2.subject_id is null;
```